# Using HAVING clause, COUNT aggregation and GROUP BY at once with Sequelize to filter data

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I have a MySQL database with tables `dataset` and `data_record`. The two are associated through a 1 to many association (`dataset.hasMany(data_records)`). I would like to filter the datasets by the properties of the `data_record`s. Say, show only datasets that contain some number of data_records which each have a distinct value for some attribute.

I have the following SQL, which gives the correct result:

```
SELECT dataset.id, dataset.name 
FROM dataset
WHERE dataset.id IN 
        (SELECT dataset_id 
         FROM
               (SELECT DISTINCT dataset_id, some_attribute 
               FROM data_record) AS data 
        GROUP BY data.dataset_id 
        HAVING COUNT(some_attribute) = :filterValue);, value
```

I have tried a number of things in Sequelize, but I can't make the having clause work there. I get the correct result using sequelize.query(). I appreciate any tips on this, been stuck here for quite some time and getting tired decrypting sequelize errors. It seems that you can no longer use `sequelize.where` inside `having`. Let me know if you think I should just write the queries in SQL.

EDIT: To clarify, I'm trying to accomplish the query using `Model.findAll()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A subquery in the FROM clause could work.

This would also support sequelize, where if it's not working correctly in the having clause.  (I do not use sequelize so can't confirm that this works).

```
SELECT dataset.id, dataset.name 
FROM dataset 
JOIN (SELECT dataset_id, COUNT(DISTINCT some_attribute) unique_some_attributes 
               FROM data_record
               GROUP BY dataset_id) a
WHERE dataset.id = a.dataset_id
AND unique_some_attributes = :filterValue;
```

Comment: I believe you misunderstood the problem slightly. `SELECT DISTINCT dataset_id, some_attribute` will show all distinct combinations of those two attributes, and I want to count how many different attributes "some_attribute" (say, test subjects) appear with a certain dataset, to filter datasets by the amount of different test subjects, for example.

I tested your suggestion, but it didn't return any tuples with some test values I tried. Edit: And some other test values returned wrong results.

Comment: After further tests, I realized that your suggestion actually returns the datasets in which a certain attribute value appears `filterValue`times. I want to return the datasets that have `filterValue`different values for the attribute.

Comment: Yes. I must have misunderstood your question.   Can you pls explain to me what you are trying to return in the query.  I will fix the query to match your requirements.

Comment: Sure. I want to return the ids and names of those `Datasets` that are associated to a user-specified number of different `Subjects`. Datasets and Subjects are linked through `Data records`, with one record having a single dataset and subject stored in the attributes `dataset_id` and `subject_id`. The query in the OP does the job, but I can't make it work as a Sequelize `findAll` call. Thanks for your help again :)

Comment: Yeah that does return the correct result, I mean isn't what you do there just what `HAVING` is. I'll see if I can make that work with `findAll`.

Comment: Yes, but sometimes it doesn't work well in queries to filter on the HAVING in that way, especially when you need additional data from other tables.  In your case, the issue is outside MySQL, with sequelize. Please accept this answer if it does work for you.

Comment: I accepted the answer. I'll see if I can make the Sequelize part work if I have some extra time within this project since I already developed a workaround with raw queries.